# Integrating Datatables into Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I'm very new to Drupal and I'm having trouble finding a way to implement the [Datatable module](http://drupal.org/project/datatables) into my website.

I'd like to use the module to display data on a variety of content pages. I need the flexibility of easily uploading the data from a spreadsheet, but I don't that being possible explicitly through using the Views.

The DataTables module integrates the jQuery plugin [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/index) into Drupal as a Views style and a callable theme function. Rendering a Datatable through Views seems much more time consuming than attempting to load it by simply calling for the necessary script or functions directly and pointing it to spreadsheet code already formatted for display as a table.

I've found [a way to render tables programmatically](http://webwash.net/tutorials/using-datatables-drupal-7), but I'm unsure how to implement that method or if formatting a spreadsheet for it is practical.

I've also attempted linking the necessary Datatables files and script into my html.tpl.php file from [the basic Datatable example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html), but it doesn't format my table data as a Datatable.

Answer (score 1):

are you wanting to upload a .csv text file and then have the tables generated?

That's what the node-import module does and it works pretty well:

drupal.org/documentation/modules/node_import

It uses Views to display the content but I also use it to display google charts with printer data from a csv file.

Comment: Awesome! I ended up using the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), but it works!